# IndexError when parsing string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to parse the string if the one that I desired is appeared at the first character but I end up with `IndexError`. So that code does not continue executing.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 68, in <module>
    if i[0] == 'U':
['U0', '1000', '-35.3632619', '149.165237', '-0.073', 'None', 'None', 'None', '353', 'ai0.0', '']
IndexError: string index out of range

U is: 
0
```

Here is the code:

```
string2 = 'U0,1000,-35.3632619,149.165237,-0.073,None,None,None,353,ai0.0,'

listt = string2.split(',')
print listt

for i in listt:

    if i[0] == 'U':
         print "U is:"
         print i[1]
```

Comment: What happens is that when `i = ''` for the last string in `listt`, i.e., `i` is the empty string, `i[0]` is not defined. What are you trying to achieve? Do you just want the first result?

Comment: Okey. I've got the point. When there is an empty string, there is no such index.
This is just an example. I want to parse the data according to the indicator that is placed at the beginning of the string. Do you know a better method?

What I simply trying to achieve is, I am receiving a byte stream from a UDP socket. I pickle.loads it and parse to related variable as I described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `string2 = 'U0,1000,-35.3632619,149.165237,-0.073,None,None,None,353,ai0.0,'` to `string2 = 'U0,1000,-35.3632619,149.165237,-0.073,None,None,None,353,ai0.0'` and it should just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should search for the first Character as U

string2 = 'U0,1000,-35.3632619,149.165237,-0.073,None,None,None,353,ai0.0,'

```
listt = string2.split(',')
print(listt)

for i in listt:

    if i.startswith('U'):
         print("U is:")
         print(i[1])
```

> ['U0', '1000', '-35.3632619', '149.165237', '-0.073', 'None', 'None', 'None', '353', 'ai0.0', '']
>   U is:
>   0
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

As you have printed listt, it's `['U0', '1000', '-35.3632619', '149.165237', '-0.073', 'None', 'None', 'None', '353', 'ai0.0', '']`

The last one is `''` so i[0] will raise the exception.

try this:

```
for i in listt:
    if not i:
        continue
    if i[0] == 'U':
        print "U is:"
        print i[1]
```